# Can you indicate to Android the time to wait or tell it that the app is still "active" before displaying "App isn't responding? If so, how?

Tags: android, sleep

I'd like to know the code or configuration needed to set that.

In my app, there are some places where I'm willingly make the app to sleep for several seconds, as it's needed for some reasons, with a Thread.sleep(long millis) function.

Problem is that on some Android APIS, at least on 25 and 26, usually that system message pops up in few seconds, confusing the user and maybe even causing the application not to fulfill the needed operations that need to happen while that sleep is happening if the user ends the app, which might cause even malfunctioning of the application.

I'd like to find a way of either forcing Android to wait for a good time like, for example, 1 minute, or to make Android aware that it's not that app isn't responding, that is willingly on a Thread.sleep function.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to find a way of either forcing Android to wait for a good time like, for example, 1 minute, or to make Android aware that it's not that app isn't responding, that is willingly on a Thread.sleep function.

**TL;DR** there is none.

Android apps should at all times be able to yield their position in the foreground to other apps. It's up to the users if they want to wait while some lengthy download is taking place or if they prefer to do something else and come back later.

You can't execute `Thread.sleep()` on the UI thread for long because this would "freeze the UI".

An example: Users should be able to leave your app by pressing the BACK `Button` at any time they wish to. If your method is blocking the UI thread, `Activity#onBackPressed()` can't be executed so the users can't quit.

What can you do? Move the heavy work to another thread (using e.g. AsyncTask or IntentService or some plain worker thread) and show some type of progress indicator to the users if necessary. You can/ should also toggle visibility or enabled state of `Button`s etc. if required to avoid clicks which can't be processed at that point in time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the point is that the user shouldn't be able to exit app no matter the reason, as starting it again before that operation is performed may cause the app to not work, anyway I've checked that unlike old API versions that caused the app not to work any longer, now there seems to be just a system message that displays until that operations are done.

Comment: @user2638180 - "as starting it again before that operation is performed may cause the app to not work" - it is definitely possible to write an android app which behaves like it should from the application logic point of view as well as from the  "does not crash and plays nice with the other apps" point of view. IMO this is what one should try to achieve, not least because it will make the app more stable on different devices and for different android versions. If you want to rely on that the worst which can happen to you is that system dialog then at least test thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an implementation problem. The system message, known as ANR (Application Not Responding) occurs when the application cannot respond to user inputs, this may be caused by Ui thread blocking and that may be your case.
To avoid blocking the UI Thread just run your long time operations asynchronously. There are many ways to do that. You could use AsyncTask, AsyncTaskLoader, Thread, RxJava... Here you have some links to help you with that:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr

https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/content/en/Unit%203/71c_asynctask_and_asynctaskloader_md.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't help for my case, check comment in the @OxOnosugar answer if you wish.